# How to find out what program is trying to open the GNOME keyring?

Tags: security, password, gnome-keyring

Some tens of minutes after I login with a KDE session, I get a modal `gcr-prompter` window asking for the master password of the GNOME keyring.
The prompt does not include any information about what program is trying to use the keyring or even if the prompter is started by `gnome-keyring`.

From the security perspective, I find it kind of annoying that I need to enter an important password without even knowing which program is asking for the password.

**Is there some way to find out which program requested access to the keyring?**

The whole desktop is locked (all keystrokes go into the password field) and canceling several times cancels the whole prompt. On the Linux console I see the process started by `gnome-keyring`, but still I don't know which program is trying to open the keyring.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I would try to run `sudo ps afxj` or `sudo pstree` to identify the parent process

Comment: No success yet. I already looked at `ps` and wasn't able to find out what started the prompt. Unfortunately I do not even know how to reproduce the prompt, so I cannot easily test.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. It is annoying to keep clicking "cancel", but I'm not going to enter my password without knowing why.
The fact that I suffer 0 consequences for not entering my password is what really bothers me here: obviously, whatever is asking for my password does not really need it, and thus should not have it!

It is annoying that all the other google hits I find when searching are about how to no longer require a password for the keyring on login. That isn't acceptable, just make me manually enter it when actually needed, please.

Comment: @ChrisElrod I think in my case it was the evolution alarm notifier (trying to open CalDAV calendars), but this does not answer the question how to properly find out which program opens the dialog. I wonder if one should report it as a Gnome bug, because I also think that it is a security issue not to know which program wants to access the keyring.